# Http 400 in appengine when using URLFetch with Http Method 'DELETE'

Tags: java, google-app-engine, facebook-graph-api, urlfetch

I've been unable to make a "DELETE" request using the code below :

```
URLFetchService fetchService = URLFetchServiceFactory.getURLFetchService();
URL posturl = new URL("http://www.example.com/comment?token=xxx");
HTTPResponse response = fetchService.fetch(new HTTPRequest(posturl, HTTPMethod.DELETE));
int responseCode = response.getResponseCode();
```

This is for Google Appengine. The 'DELETE' request is for the facebook graph API. The above code gives me a status code 400 - Bad Request.

This is for [face4j](https://github.com/nischal/face4j) an open source java library that I've built for the facebook graph API.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an App Engine problem; it just means that the destination webserver wouldn't accept your request.

If you're actually trying to send a DELETE to example.com, that's your problem. If that's supposed to be a scrubbed URL, you've omitted the detail that would facilitate troubleshooting.

Comment: The facebook-graph-api tag is a hint.

Comment: The end URLs are facebook graph API. I'm unable to do it with URLFetch however it works with apache httpclient. But in order to support appengine, I need to make it work with URLFetch.

Comment: @Nischal If you're getting a 400, though, that's still because the server is returning that status code. Something about your request is invalid.